# Spring REST API - HEAD Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman

I have built a `REST API` with `Spring`, and I was looking into the `HEAD` Request; how do I know if it is working?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employees", method= RequestMethod.GET) //used to get all employees
        
@RequestMapping(value="/employees", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD}) //same but I added the head request method
```

In Postman, both of these return the same values under Headers in a HEAD Request - so do I need to add the `RequestMethod.HEAD` or not? How can I check it is working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestMapping` methods mapped to `GET` are also implicitly mapped to `HEAD`, i.e. there is no need to have `HEAD` explicitly declared. An `HTTP HEAD` request is processed as if it were an `HTTP GET` except instead of writing the body only the number of bytes are counted and the `Content-Length` header set.